# Can fire create pressure if it released it energy as fast as an explosion

Tags: energy, combustion

Since fire release energy, I wanna know if it can create a shockwave if it release it energy as fast as an explosion

Comment: Petrol engine with its moving pistons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, if you have some way of mixing the fuel you wish to burn with air before you light it. For example, if you pour some gasoline onto the ground and light it with a spark, then it bursts into flame and burns bit by bit until the gasoline is all gone. If you instead pour the gasoline onto the top of a large pile of sticks and branches so it splashes about and saturates the air in the pile with gasoline vapors as it flows downwards- and THEN you light it- the vapor mixed with air will explode with enough force to blow the pile of sticks and branches into the air and break the windows in your house nearby. This is called an *air-fuel explosive* and it is very dangerous! It might kill you as well, so do not try this at home.